# Sending out notification from a PostgreSQL RDS instance (without pg_notify)?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, cron, alert, amazon-rds

We have a Postgre RDS instance where new data is inserted every 5 seconds. We'd like to set up some alerts based on the readings.

Theoretically we should set up a trigger with corresponding function to compare the value and to send out a notification which will then be LISTENed by a script, like described in this [tutorial](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/13/how-to-send-mail-from-database/).

However, function *pg_notify* is not available in Amazon's RDS. Is there any alternative way for this other than scan the table for update every couple of seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be better to separate these; those really are three separate questions.

Comment: `pg_notify` *is* available in RDS. At least as of november 2016.

Comment: Where is `pg_notify` documented as being available in RDS?

Comment: @Glyph https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-enhancements-support-for-new-minor-versions-logical-replication-and-amazon-rds-postgresql-as-a-source-for-aws-dms/